# Extracting aac from mka with batch doesn't work, commandline works

Tags: batch

My first try: As described extracting (no reencoding) aac from mka works only on commandline, not as batch.

Working:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i "Testmka.mka" -vn -acodec copy "Testmka.aac"
```

Not working as batch from a desktop shortcut:

```
"C:\Users\user\MediathekView\convert mp2 to mp3\\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -loglevel error -i "C:\Users\user\MediathekView\convert mp2 to mp3\Test.mka" -vn -acodec copy C:\Users\user\MediathekView\convert mp2 to mp3\Test.aac" )
Error:
[NULL @ 03ea3c80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'C:\Users\user\MediathekView\convert'
C:\Users\user\MediathekView\convert: Invalid argument
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

// **Solved**.
Nothing was wrong, but using Notepad as editor results in a non-visible sign within the last `%%~dpnf.aac`.
Even if there was no `CR` or `LF` - this was the problem.

Re-writing all and it works as expected.

The full command to extract aac without reencoding is:

```
for %%f in (%*) do (
    "%~dp0\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -loglevel error -i "%%~dpnxf" -acodec copy "%%~dpnf.aac"
   )
```

Make a desktop shortcut (not copy) and drop all mka to get the aac.

Karl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).